# I am getting a numberformatexception

Tags: java

I am trying to search a file, a small one, for a string that I input and then output only the double values on that line. I am getting an error each time I try something. Also I am trying to avoid using loops so its a little challenging(I know there is a while loop but I will deal with that next.. Any help would be appreciated. Oh yeah and the text file looks like this(those two top stock tickers).

```
AAPL 101.50
MSFT 45.84


File file = new File("stocks.txt");
        Scanner ticker = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
                String phone;
                System.out.print("\nEnter a stock ticker: ");
                String that = ticker.next();



                while(scan.hasNext())
              {      
                  phone = scan.nextLine();
                  //double b = Double.parseDouble(phone);
                 if(phone.contains(that))
                 System.out.println(phone + "\n");

              }     




one of the errors is:

Enter a stock ticker: AAPL
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at hw01a.java.Hw01aJava.main(Hw01aJava.java:36)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)

the other is:

Enter a stock ticker: AAPL
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "AAPL 101.50"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at hw01a.java.Hw01aJava.main(Hw01aJava.java:34)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)
```

Comment: What error do you get on what line?

Comment: I only get an error when i try to print out the value for phone.

Comment: Show us the exception message.  The whole thing.  Precisely.

Comment: the way the program is now, it does not error, but it returns the whole line and I only need the double value on that line. That is were I am getting an error everytime I try to return just part of that line.

Comment: Post code and example of input which will let us reproduce your problem.

Comment: So show us the "whole line" that it is returning!

Comment: ok ill put it up there with the rest of the code

Comment: Don't post code or important informations in comments  (code can't be properly formatted in comment, and important informations should be part of your original question). To update it use [edit] option.

Comment: Thank you, all three answers were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the double number by using substring :

```
// will extract 101.23 from "AAPL 101.23"
System.out.println(phone.substring(phone.indexOf(' ') + 1) + "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to call `Double.parseDouble(phone)` when `phone` is (for example) `"AAPL 101.23"`, that is going to fail.  The `parseDouble` method expects the entire argument string to be a valid double.  Your string has stuff at the start that is not numeric.  Hence the exception ...

How to deal with that?

You need to skip over the non-numeric stuff somehow:

- You could "parse" the line into components / fields using `String.split(...)`.
- You could use the `Scanner` to read the fields, instead of reading an entire line.
- Possibly other ways too ...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a string into a double which is not a number. The string contains the stock ticker too. What you can do instead is something like this:

```
while(scan.hasNext())
              {      
                 phone = scan.nextLine();
                 String[] phoneContents = phone.split(" ");
                 double b = Double.parseDouble(phoneContents[1]);
                 if(phone.contains(that))
                 System.out.println(phone + "\n");
              }
```